# How to combine two list into one list element wise?

Tags: python, list

For example, if I have:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]` & `B = [4, 5, 6]
```

and I would like to have:

```
C = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: you can use zip

Comment: `list(zip(A,B))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple and zip to meet this requirement.

Sample code -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]

>>> c = tuple(zip(a,b))
>>> print(c)
((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin function called zip for this:

```
[list(ab) for ab in zip(a,b)]
```

Or using map and zip:

```
list(map(list, zip(a,b)))
```

Both return:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [list(x) for x in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [110]: A = [1,2,3]

In [111]: B = [4,5,6]

In [112]: list(zip(A,B))
Out[112]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```